Visual Studio namespaces and Intelisense stop working
I've recently reinstalled Windows 11 on my PC, as well as Unity Hub (3.9.1) and Visual Studio 2022 (17.11.4) as it is required, with the default extensions provided by the installer.
But for some reason, Visual Studio keeps ignoring namespaces and Intelisense as a result, even for plain C# at some times.
Oh, the error only happens on Visual Studio, because some errors such as interface methods not implemented on script, still appear on Unity's console, but not in Visual Studio.
What i've tried so far:

My External Script Editor on Unity is set to Visual Studio 2022.
Repaired Visual Studio through the installer.
Reinstalled Unity's extensions for Visual Studio through the installer.
Reinstalled Visual Studio.
Project Settings > Player > Api Compatibility Level = .NET Framework
Rebooting my PC.
Updating both Visual Studio and Unity's Editor.

Restarting Visual Studio seems to fix, only to happen again if it sits idle, or when I create and open a new file.
Here's the version of everything:

Unity Hub => 3.9.1
Visual Studio 2022 => 17.11.4
Unity Editor => 2022.3.28f1

If there is some important info missing, please let me know.
Print of External Tools page on Unity

Click "Regenerate project files" in Unity to rebuild the .csproj files, which may help Visual Studio sync properly.

Just did that, but still not showing the correct Intelisense.
VIsual Studio released a new version, I'll try updating to see if it works.

Updated to Visual Studio 17.11.5 and yet the same problem...
